# Extend the wireless using Asus RT-AC66U router

Tags: wireless-networking

Currently my office is using xyzel router, and I plan to extend the 5GHZ wireless because the office space is very big, and can't receive signal on the other end. But I have LAN cable connected from the main router to the other side which I want to extend.

What I plan to do is to buy Asus RT-AC66U router, and then change it to Access Point. Connect the ASUS router into the LAN port.
But the only problem I need is to maintain the same SSID. So that all the staff don't need to keep switching WIFI ssid when walk from one point the another.

How to do it? Can the asus RT-AC66U setup work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just set the same SSID and password on the AC66 in AP mode. Its about that simple.